# Filtering dependent data table, returns results from main table

Tags: postgresql, search, sphinx

Can I search in **dependent** data tables but returns results from **main** table?

This problem occurs where we have N x N relation in database like in example below: every user can have multiple locations but even if user has many location it is still one physical person.

I want to query sphinx with condition in table **locations** and return set should be from table **users**.

> Query results will be filter by geo coordinates GEODIST() but its only
>   information because its not the main subject of this question. Goal is
>   for example: **find persons who have location in 20 kilometers radius from some explicit point**.

SQL structure

```
TABLE users
id PRIMARY KEY
name TEXT
etc...

TABLE locations
id PRIMARY KEY
name TEXT
coord_x FLOAT
coord_y FLOAT
etc...

TABLE user_location
user_id INTEGER FK
location_id INTEGER FK
```

Of course I can simply JOIN this 3 tables in Sphinx sql_query and filter this set but then I got **duplicated persons** when person have more than one location.

Any tips how to achieve this goal with Sphinx Search?

Comment: 20 km from where? From another location or from some explicit point?

Comment: 20 km from defined incoming variable, for example we have coords X, Y and want to find persons in circle 20 km

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Of course I can simply JOIN this 3 tables in Sphinx sql_query and filter this set but then I got duplicated persons when person have more than one location.

Just add a GROUP BY to the sphinx query, then will only ever get own row per user.

---

You will need to make the `users.id` a sphinx **attribute** (so can group on it) and use a primary key from `user_location` as the sphinx document-id (so its unique)

*(gets more complicated if have users that **don't** have locations, and still want to be able to search then - without the location filter. But it can still be done. Perhaps use a second source on the index, to find the unlocationed users)*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.*
FROM users u
JOIN user_location ul ON ul.user_id = u.id
JOIN locations l ON l.id = ul.location_id
WHERE ((l.coord_x - <<your X>>) * (l.coord_x - <<your X>>)) +
      ((l.coord_y - <<your Y>>) * (l.coord_y - <<your Y>>)) < 400;
```

You might want to wrap this in a SQL language function that takes the location coordinates as parameters and possibly the distance too. Note that this code assumes that coord_x and coord_y are in kilometers. If in some other unit, change the value 400 accordingly.

Note also that the query does not compute the distance to the given point by taking the square root of the squared differences in the two cardinal directions: you are not interested in the distance itself but only in locations being closer than a specified distance from a specified point. So you square that distance and then forget about the square root which is computationally expensive. If your locations table has many records, you will notice the difference.

Comment: that seems to be a postgresql query? I thought the question was asking about sphinx search?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM user_location ul
  JOIN locations l ON l.id = ul.location_id
  WHERE ul.user_id = u.id
  AND l.coord_x ...
  AND l.coord_y ...
  );
```